# Customize startup message Laravel Octane + Swoole

Tags: laravel, swoole, laravel-octane

When Laravel Octane with Swoole is starting, he show the message on console:

```
INFO  Server running…

Local: http://0.0.0.0:80

Press Ctrl+C to stop the server
```

I want remove this message and customize using one custom message.